# Creating a keyword structure on Core Data and search that big animal

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data

I am about to create a coredata database of pictures. These pictures will have keywords. One picture may have keywords like "bird", "eagle", "flying", "nest", etc.

OK I can create an entity one to many to link the Keyword entity to the Pictures entity but my problem is this, I will use the search controller to scan the database as the user types on the search box. Will be coredata fast enough to search as the user type and show the results without clogging the application?

By the way, thinking about it now, it will be a pretty complex query to send to coredata! And how do I combine queries? I mean, suppose the user search for eagle. The database can contain different types of eagles but then the user types "bald" and the app must combing "eagle" and "bald", or, pictures that contain both...

What is the better way of doing that structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data is very fast. If you index your keywords, it will make queries faster. As for combining multiple search terms you can you use an NSCompoundPredicate.